# How to access a state to other class in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-pages

I want to access the state declared in MainActivity class to the class Hamburgicon. The state of mainactivity class can be accessed in the same class and please tell me how to access the state in other classes or the whole project.

Comment: ***PLEASE STOP YELLING AT US!*** Writing in ALL CAPS is annoying, because it's very hard to read, and it's generally considered **SHOUTING** at your audience, which is just plain rude - **don't do it** and fix your post here ASAP!

Comment: Improved formatting. Try to avoid capitalised words.

Answer (score 4):

You can send your state as props from MainActivity to other classes or functional components.
In your case for instance:

```
HamburgerIcon = (props) => {
   return (
     <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
       <TouchableOpacity 
         onPress={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)} 
       >
         <Text>{props.item}</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
     </View>
   );
}

class MainActivity extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        a: 'ABCD'
    };
  }

  render()
  {
    return(
      <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>
        <Text> this.state.a </Text>
        <HamburgerIcon item={this.state.a}/>    
      </View>
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @kosalram it worked . once again thank you so much

Comment: @ Kosalram when i use <HamburgerIcon item={this.state.a}/> the things which i have is displaying in the main activity class

Comment: Could you explain your expected behavior?

Comment: if i have a image in HamburgerIcon class it is dislpaying in mainactivity class

Comment: i have this code at the bottom of the mainactivity class
const FirstActivity_StackNavigator = StackNavigator({
      First: { 
        screen: MainActivity, 
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          title: 'MainActivity',
          headerLeft : <HamburgerIcon navigationProps={ navigation }/>,
           
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#FF9800'
          },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
        })
      },
    });
and i want to access the state of main activity to this title
i want to bind the city name to title

Comment: Is HamburgerIcon is a separate screen?
What I presume from your above reply is that you are having a stack navigator, in which your MainActivity is parent screen.
If I'm not wrong you are trying to pass props from one screen to another, am I right?